# Google Fusion Tables with Derek Eder's Searchable Map Template - Can I layer more than one map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using the [Searchable Map Template](https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template) to display a map which has shapes that layer over one another. I need to be able to control the layering of all the shapes displayed on the fusion table.

I have done some research, and apparently there is no way to use Fusion Tables column values to control layering. So my shapes are just randomly layering above and below each other.

I found a feature called [Fusion Tables Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) which provides the ability to layer maps, but I'm not sure how to implement the layers in the Searchable Map Template.

Is there in fact a way to control layering with Fusion tables? If not, is there a way to get the Searchable Map Template to display more than one separate Fusion Table map?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! Take a look at this example repo https://github.com/JackDougherty/FusionTable-Map-2-layers

Comment: This is going to work for me, but I can't upvote it becuase my reputation is too low. Thanks Derek.